# Replace improper commas in CSV file

Tags: regex, r, csv

This question may have been asked before, but I couldn't find it. I have a list of CSV files (439 or so) where, in a few of the files, someone also used commas in editorial comments. The result is that I can't put the files into a data frame, since the files now do not have the same number of elements after splitting them. Anyways, the problem I'm facing looks like this:

```
vec1 <- paste("484,1213,0,62.0006,1,go -- late F1 max, but glide?")
vec2 <- paste("467,1387,0,62.0026,1,goes2")

ls <- list(vec1, vec2)
```

What I want to do is to have a data frame with six columns. If there wasn't a comma in the editorial comments for `vec1`, I could use (and have been using, until I found this problematic example) the following:

```
df <- ldply(ls, function(x)unlist(strsplit(x[1], split = ",")))
```

However, I'm getting the obvious error message that the results do not have the same number of lengths. Is there any way of getting rid of that comma, or turning it into a semi-colon, or ensuring that, if there are 7 elements in a vector, that 6 and 7 are combined?

If it helps, this is how I'm reading the files in R (I'm using `scan` because there is other information in the files that I want. There's some odd encoding issues going on here as well, but this seems to work).

```
data <- scan(file, fileEncoding="latin1", blank.lines.skip = FALSE, what = "list", sep = "\n", quiet = TRUE)
```

Comment: if the undesired comma is always in the last element and you have "--" before, you can maybe put "--" as comment character in the `scan` call so it will be ignored ?

Comment: HI, thanks. I think that might have worked. By the way, is it possible to have "--" as a comment char (I get an error message, but the single ("-" seems to work).

Comment: If you need the comments, you still can replace the 6th comma with a semicolon and use your previous solution: `gsub("((?:[^,]*,){5}[^,]*),", "\\1;", vec1, perl=TRUE)`. However, it will not "normalize" any other commas that might follow.

Comment: @JoeF, no idea, I thought "--" would work actually and don't see why it doesn't... but never used more than a character

Comment: @stribizhev or `sub("^([^,]+,){5}[^,]+\\K,", ";", vec1, perl=T)`

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. It's good to know different ways of solving the problem. Out of curiosity, what is the proper etiquette for acknowledging solutions that work but are in comments instead of answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the comments, you still can replace the 6th comma with a semicolon and use your previous solution:

```
gsub("((?:[^,]*,){5}[^,]*),", "\\1;", vec1, perl=TRUE)
```

**Regex explanation**:

- `((?:[^,]*,){5}[^,]*)` - a capturing group that we will reference to as Group 1 with `\\1` in the replacement pattern, matching

  - `(?:[^,]*,){5}` - 5 sequences of non-comma characters followed by a comma
  - `[^,]*` - 0 or more non-commas
- `,` - the comma we'll turn into a `;` in the replacement

Or (as @CathG pointed out, a `\\K` operator can also be used with Perl-like expressions)

```
sub("^([^,]+,){5}[^,]+\\K,", ";", vec1, perl=T)
```

From [PCRE documentation](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> The  escape sequence `\K` causes any previously matched characters not to be included in the final matched sequence.

However, it will not "normalize" any other commas that might follow.

Comment: Since it helped, I am posting the answer. Actually, I do not see any point in using `\K` here, as just a backreference yields an analoguous result.